# How can I assign a specific color according to whether night mode is activated or not on the device?

Tags: android, android-night-mode

I need to display a large amount of text in a textView, of which certain parts must be **red** when the device is in day mode and **amber** when the device is in night mode.

Since I do not have access to the context when the text content is generated, I have created a utility class called `ColorUtils` and a property `isNightMode`, to choose the color that should be applied to the texts:

```
var isNightMode = false
val redCode: String
    get() = if (isNightMode) "#FFDAB9" else "#A52A2A"
```

In the Manifest I have added the value `uiMode` to `configChanges` and in the fragment I have this:

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)
    when (newConfig.uiMode and Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK) {
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_NO -> {
            ColorUtils.isNightMode = false
        }
        Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES -> {
            ColorUtils.isNightMode = true
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The code does not always work as expected, as you can see in the reproduction above.

This is what happens:

- The sequence starts in **day mode**. Everything correct: color of the **top bar blue**, **background color** of the screens with Recyclerview **blue** and **partial text** color in **red**.
- I make a **first change to night mode** and the following happens: **background color** of the Recyclerview is fine, it is **black**, but color of the **top bar** is **blue** when it should be **black**. Same problem on the other two screens that follow. Also the **partial text**, which should have changed to **amber**, remains in **red**.
- Then I go back to day mode and everything is still correct in that mode.
- Finally, I go back to **night mode**. And the color of the **partial text** is now correct, it appears **amber**, but the color of the **top bar** never turns black, remaining **blue**.

Why is this happening and how could I resolve it from the first switch from day mode to night mode?

Comment: When you say you are handling configuration changes, that means you are responsible for informing every single component and every single view with that change - you've specifically turned off the system automatically re-inflating views (which would cause them to again retrieve colors from your theme for instance). So where do you inform every one of the views that was reading from your `ColorUtils` of the color changing?